# ERROR 1728 (HY000): Cannot load from mysql.db. The table is probably corrupted

Tags: php, mysql, macos, apache

I recently installed Mac OS 10.14.5 on my Mac mini (late 2012).  I did a mysqldump --all-databases on my laptop running MySQL 5.6.15, copied the file over to my Mac mini, and imported the dump into the 8.0.16 MySQL Community Server - GPL that came pre-installed with Mac OS 10.14.5.  When trying to access webpages that make use of MySQL, I get the error message:

mysqli_connect(): The server requested authentication method unknown to the client [caching_sha2_password]

I thought this was because the dump hadn't included the MySQL DB (including mysql.user), and sure enough, there were no users other than mysql.infoschema, mysql.session, mysql.sys, and root; none of the users I had created were in mysql.users.  So I tried to create the user I had defined in my php webpage:

create user 'username'@'localhost' identified by 'password';

and got the following error message:

ERROR 1728 (HY000): Cannot load from mysql.db. The table is probably corrupted

So I changed the login credentials of the php webpage to use root and still got the error message:

mysqli_connect(): The server requested authentication method unknown to the client [caching_sha2_password]

The code I use to connect to the DB is:

function connectDBi($str_server, $str_username, $str_password, $str_database, $bool_debug=false)
{
    $linkDB = mysqli_connect($str_server, $str_username, $str_password, $str_database);

```
if(!$linkDB)
{
    if($bool_debug)
    {
        echo '<div style="border:1px solid blue;">';
        echo backtrace(debug_backtrace())
            .'UNsuccessful connection "'.$str_database.'" '
            .'on "'.$str_server.'" '
            ;
        echo '</div>'."\n";
    } // if($bool_debug) else
} // if(!$linkDB)
else
{
    if($bool_debug)
    {
        echo '<div style="border:1px solid blue;">';
        echo backtrace(debug_backtrace())
            .'SUCCESSFUL connection to "'.$str_database.'" '
            .'on "'.$str_server.'" '
            ;
        echo '</div>'."\n";
    }
    return $linkDB;
} // if(!$linkDB) else
```

} // function connectDBi()

Answer (score 1):

You need to repair the mysql.db table with this command:

```
mysql> REPAIR TABLE mysql.db;
```

You can find a similar question with an explanation [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/229353/error-code-1728-cannot-load-from-mysql-db-the-table-is-probably-corrupted) but it is caused by moving a database from a previous version of MySQL to version 8.

Comment: Sorry, I should mentioned that I had tried this.  Doing so results in Msg_text:

Comment: And Msg_text would be...?

Comment: The storage engine for the table doesn't support repair